# Cycles z pass is not expect (1.09 times larger)

Tags: python, rendering, cycles-render-engine, scripting

I am trying to generate synthetic data using blender for disparity prediction. I used z-pass in Cycles for depth ground-truth, but I find out that the z-pass value is always 1.09 times larger than actual depth.

There is a demo, I use functions from [3x4 camera matrix from blender camera](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38009/3x4-camera-matrix-from-blender-camera) to get extrinsic data.

```
import bpy
import os
os.environ["OPENCV_IO_ENABLE_OPENEXR"]="1"
import cv2
from mathutils import Matrix, Vector
import numpy as np

################################################################
#from https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38009/3x4-camera-matrix-from-blender-camera

#---------------------------------------------------------------
# 3x4 P matrix from Blender camera
#---------------------------------------------------------------

# BKE_camera_sensor_size
def get_sensor_size(sensor_fit, sensor_x, sensor_y):
    if sensor_fit == 'VERTICAL':
        return sensor_y
    return sensor_x

# BKE_camera_sensor_fit
def get_sensor_fit(sensor_fit, size_x, size_y):
    if sensor_fit == 'AUTO':
        if size_x >= size_y:
            return 'HORIZONTAL'
        else:
            return 'VERTICAL'
    return sensor_fit

# Build intrinsic camera parameters from Blender camera data
#
# See notes on this in 
# blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15102/what-is-blenders-camera-projection-matrix-model
# as well as
# https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/120063/3581
def get_calibration_matrix_K_from_blender(camd):
    if camd.type != 'PERSP':
        raise ValueError('Non-perspective cameras not supported')
    scene = bpy.context.scene
    f_in_mm = camd.lens
    scale = scene.render.resolution_percentage / 100
    resolution_x_in_px = scale * scene.render.resolution_x
    resolution_y_in_px = scale * scene.render.resolution_y
    sensor_size_in_mm = get_sensor_size(camd.sensor_fit, camd.sensor_width, camd.sensor_height)
    sensor_fit = get_sensor_fit(
        camd.sensor_fit,
        scene.render.pixel_aspect_x * resolution_x_in_px,
        scene.render.pixel_aspect_y * resolution_y_in_px
    )
    pixel_aspect_ratio = scene.render.pixel_aspect_y / scene.render.pixel_aspect_x
    if sensor_fit == 'HORIZONTAL':
        view_fac_in_px = resolution_x_in_px
    else:
        view_fac_in_px = pixel_aspect_ratio * resolution_y_in_px
    pixel_size_mm_per_px = sensor_size_in_mm / f_in_mm / view_fac_in_px
    s_u = 1 / pixel_size_mm_per_px
    s_v = 1 / pixel_size_mm_per_px / pixel_aspect_ratio

    # Parameters of intrinsic calibration matrix K
    u_0 = resolution_x_in_px / 2 - camd.shift_x * view_fac_in_px
    v_0 = resolution_y_in_px / 2 + camd.shift_y * view_fac_in_px / pixel_aspect_ratio
    skew = 0 # only use rectangular pixels

    K = Matrix(
        ((s_u, skew, u_0),
        (   0,  s_v, v_0),
        (   0,    0,   1)))
    return K

# Returns camera rotation and translation matrices from Blender.
# 
# There are 3 coordinate systems involved:
#    1. The World coordinates: "world"
#       - right-handed
#    2. The Blender camera coordinates: "bcam"
#       - x is horizontal
#       - y is up
#       - right-handed: negative z look-at direction
#    3. The desired computer vision camera coordinates: "cv"
#       - x is horizontal
#       - y is down (to align to the actual pixel coordinates 
#         used in digital images)
#       - right-handed: positive z look-at direction
def get_3x4_RT_matrix_from_blender(cam):
    # bcam stands for blender camera
    R_bcam2cv = Matrix(
        ((1, 0,  0),
        (0, -1, 0),
        (0, 0, -1)))

    # Transpose since the rotation is object rotation, 
    # and we want coordinate rotation
    # R_world2bcam = cam.rotation_euler.to_matrix().transposed()
    # T_world2bcam = -1*R_world2bcam @ location
    #
    # Use matrix_world instead to account for all constraints
    location, rotation = cam.matrix_world.decompose()[0:2]
    R_world2bcam = rotation.to_matrix().transposed()

    # Convert camera location to translation vector used in coordinate changes
    # T_world2bcam = -1*R_world2bcam @ cam.location
    # Use location from matrix_world to account for constraints:     
    T_world2bcam = -1*R_world2bcam @ location

    # Build the coordinate transform matrix from world to computer vision camera
    R_world2cv = R_bcam2cv@R_world2bcam
    T_world2cv = R_bcam2cv@T_world2bcam

    # put into 3x4 matrix
    RT = Matrix((
        R_world2cv[0][:] + (T_world2cv[0],),
        R_world2cv[1][:] + (T_world2cv[1],),
        R_world2cv[2][:] + (T_world2cv[2],)
        ))
    return RT

def get_3x4_P_matrix_from_blender(cam):
    K = get_calibration_matrix_K_from_blender(cam.data)
    RT = get_3x4_RT_matrix_from_blender(cam)
    return K, RT

#################################################################
#config set

camera_pos=[0,0,1] #change this
lens=25 #change this

bpy.context.scene.render.engine ='CYCLES'
bpy.context.scene.cycles.device = 'GPU'
bpy.context.preferences.addons['cycles'].preferences.compute_device_type='CUDA'
bpy.context.preferences.addons['cycles'].preferences.get_devices()

bpy.context.scene.cycles.samples = 4 #for fast inference
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x = 1920
bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y = 1080

bpy.context.scene.use_nodes = True
bpy.context.scene.view_layers["ViewLayer"].use_pass_z = True

for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    bpy.data.objects.remove(obj,do_unlink=True)
    
#add plan
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(size=3, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=[0,0,0], scale=(1, 1, 1))

#add camera
bpy.ops.object.camera_add(enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=camera_pos, rotation=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
bpy.context.object.data.lens = lens

#render
tree = bpy.context.scene.node_tree
links = tree.links
for n in tree.nodes:
    tree.nodes.remove(n)
rl = tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeRLayers')

output_path='test'
if not os.path.exists(output_path):
    os.makedirs(output_path)

# Set up rendering depth
depth_output = tree.nodes.new(type='CompositorNodeOutputFile')
depth_output.format.file_format = 'OPEN_EXR'
depth_output.base_path = output_path
links.new(rl.outputs['Depth'], depth_output.inputs['Image'])

scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.camera = bpy.data.objects['Camera']
bpy.ops.render.render()

K, RT=get_3x4_P_matrix_from_blender(bpy.data.objects['Camera'])

print('extrinsic matrix: ', RT)
depth=cv2.imread('test/Image0001.exr', cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)
print('depth: ', np.unique(depth))
```

This code just adds a plan at [0,0,0] and add a camera at some position ([0,0,1] for example). and print the extrinsic matrix and z-pass value:

```
extrinsic matrix:  <Matrix 3x4 (1.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, -1.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000,  0.0000, -1.0000, 1.0000)>
z-pass:  [1.09]
```

The experiment results are:

1. set camera at [0,0,1], set focal length as 50: real depth is 1 but the z-pass is 1.09
2. set camera at [0,0,0.5], set focal length as 50: real depth is 0.5 but the z-pass is 0.545
3. set camera at [0,0,1], set focal length as 25: real depth is 1 but the z-pass is 1.09

My observation:
The real depth should be the distance between plan and camera origin, and z-pass is always 1.09 times larger than real depth regardless of camera position and focal length

I am very new to blender and I want to figure out where "1.09" comes from? And how could I get the ground-truth depth?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I find what's going wrong:
Should be careful of how opencv read exr file.

change

```
depth=cv2.imread('test/Image0001.exr', cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)
```

to

```
depth=cv2.imread('test/Image0001.exr', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

and the z-pass is aligned with real depth.

Edit:
reference: [Z depth values in OpenEXR do not match the objects in the scene](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120581/z-depth-values-in-openexr-do-not-match-the-objects-in-the-scene)